# Redux - Adding niche reducer to big project with single reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So I've been tasked with adding a submodule to an old, very large React project that uses Redux. Problem is that they've been using a single massive reducer for the entire application. I want to use a separate reducer, but I'm not allowed to go back and refactor their hundreds of uses of `store.getState()` etc. Is there a way to write a version of `combineReducers` that allows me to keep their massive reducer as "default" and add my reducer on the side? Something like:

```
export function reducers(appState, action) {
  return {
    ...hugereducer(appState, action),
    nicheReducer: nicheReducer(appState, action),
  }
}
```

I only ask that they can continue accessing state as they have, with `store.getState().thing` while I access it like `useSelector(state => state.nicheReducer.otherThing)`.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't this code meet your needs? What did you get?

Comment: @slideshowp2 I thought it would too, but had a weird issue. May be an issue specific to this codebase, but nicheReducer became recursive to like five levels. So nicheReducer.nicheReducer.nicheReducer.nicheReducer.nicheReducer.otherthing. Very strange.

Comment: Try creating a minimal, reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

useSelector is independent of combinereducer. It should not matter if you use mapStateToProps or useSelector. Make sure your selectors are executing with correct dependency. Treat is as syntactic sugar and you should be good. You seem to be on a right path.

Comment: Not quite what I'm after. Note that to access .thing there's no reducer name as with .otherThing.